# Do we have any conditions for someone using an SE post as a source?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

I just found the following article.

https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven

Which looks like it’s heavily based on

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23986765/330457

Comment: Can you be more specific? Can you [include](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/380847/edit) it in your answer? What exactly is "borrowed"? Perhaps provide one or more examples? Exact phrases "reused"? Code samples copied as is? Missing attribution (based on experience, this is almost always wholly or partly missing)? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/380847/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now).

Comment: @Rob that's not scraping, the content isn't the same, only based on the Stack Overflow content.

Comment: FI: This is about the OP's own post (answer), presumably plagiarised.

Comment: There is a chance a one-person company (*"Str. Dambului, nr. 96, et. 1, ap. 3, Bucharest, Romania"*) might respond positively if you phrase it in the right way (e.g., not accusatory).

Comment: [The company gave up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413386/i-reported-a-copycat-site-content-farm-and-was-responded-with-this-may-help-y/413407#comment882173_413407) a lot time ago.

Comment: What is a ‘term of being referred of some’?

Answer (score 3):

baeldung seems to have been [created in 2020](https://www.baeldung.com/company-info), well after the original Stack Overflow post. The [site's archive](https://www.baeldung.com/full_archive) says that the post was originally created in October 2016.

I'm not sure I see any copying here. The code is pretty simple and the Maven plugins themselves have similar documentation to both answers explaining how to use them. There are only so many ways to write that code.

Having said all that, the copyright owner of the Stack Overflow post is that post's original author, and only they have the ability to take any action here. All Stack Overflow has is a [licence to display the poster's content](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing).

Comment: The company may have been established then, but the site and (at least some of the) content has been around a **lot** longer than that (back to October 2011 according to https://www.baeldung.com/full_archive).

Comment: thanks @jonrsharpe I've looked through that page and found the date the site says that post was created. It's still later than the Stack Overflow post.

Comment: Please read them again. There are a lot of phrases read same.

Comment: @JinKwon Please read the final paragraph of the answer. Only you can take action by hiring a lawyer or making a DMCA request, there's nothing anyone else can do here.

Comment: I'm not looking for a lawyer here. And that's why I put the `discussion` tag.

Comment: @JinKwon Then edit the question to explain what you are looking for.